# My Samsung is stolen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, lost-phone

If they factory reset the phone and took my sim card out, can I still get my Samsung Galaxy S6. I hope you can help me please. I think the thieves already reset it and took my sim card out cause its off

Comment: Chances are not that high. The only option then would be [trying to locate it via its IMEI](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=locate+imei+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 0):

Too late to close the barn door and lock it after the horse is stolen or wandered off, but for those reading this question worried about any precaution they could take beforehand, there are several apps like Prey that you can activate after you phone goes missing that will allow you to remotely lock/wipe it, and have it report where it is; or at least where it was last turned on, if they haven't yet factory-reset it.  The enhanced (IE: paid versions) will snap the person's picture when they try unlocking the phone too.